# shouldChangeCharactersInRange affecting all UITextField's

Tags: uitextfield

I have two `UITextField` in my app, one is for price and the other is a label for a product.

I have defined both UITextField's with `@property` and `@synthesize` into the .m

```
(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
```

I'm using this method to limit the entry for the price field but it seems to be affecting both field. How to limit it to one field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method is called when any of the UITextFields have this instance set as a delegate in Interface Builder or with code.
You can check which field calls it with something like:

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if(textField == yourSynthesizedPropertyForPriceField) {
        //DO SOMETHING
    }
    return YES;
}
```